# React Navigation not working in phone in snack but working on web browser?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I am creating an app. Here it has 3 navigation setups, a drawer navigator, a stack navigator, & a bottom tab navigator. In snack if you go to the "web" tab it works perfectly. If you run it on a phone, or go to the "iOS" or "Android" tabs in snack, it does not work & says the error **"Attempting to change the getter of an unconfigurable property.**" Note that if you switch the SDK to V43, it says a different error in the 'web' tab: "cannot read property "select" of undefined", which is pointing to the library "expo-auth-session"(which I am using in the app for google authentication).

I already tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69234882/giving-error-attempting-to-change-the-getter-of-an-unconfigurable-property-in) and it did not work for me.

My code is [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@whitehatc0der/story-telling-app).

Any ideas on how to solve this error? Do I have to use a different library for navigation in react native?

Comment: you are using the old version of react-navigation (4.2.1), try using the newest version ?
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started

Comment: old version of react-navigation(4.2.1/below) are the only version that works

Comment: if I upgrade the version to the newest it will give me an error "Cannot redefine property: ThemeProvider

Comment: maybe thats different library error, newest navigation have a lots more feature and better coding structure

Comment: but that error actually points to the react-navigation.js module....... I have no idea